# Make Html page using javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I go through following links

[**How can I make JavaScript make (produce) new page?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004555/how-can-i-make-javascript-make-produce-new-page)

[**Create  and append  dynamically**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/create-div-and-append-div-dynamically)

I want to add html elements dynamically with JavaScript inside a `div` but I donot want to follow 2nd link because my javascript code will become very big and complex. Is there a way so that I can add html elements using one line of code as done in 1st link.

*I donot want to use JQuery.*

Answer (score 2):

First I am going to start by saying, *Use jQuery*. If you use jQuery you literally only need to do this:

```
$("#target").append("<p>New Paragraph</p>");
```

If you insist on using vanilla JavaScript, you will have to do like the second example you posted does it:

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

here what i want to say you can use like this

```js
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("body"); // Pick your element here as per need.

var attach_elem = "<div><p> hi creatig the p tag </p> <span>  hi creatig the span tag </span><div></div></div>"; //prepare element which you want to be in your html page.

element.write(attach_elem); // just pass the variable (want to attach in html).


//Or you can use the below code.

element.innerHTML = attach_elem; // pass variable as innerhtml to the selected element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplest option you can have

```
   <script>
    var htmlcontent = "<h1>Header</h1><p>This is some dynamically loaded content assigned using javascript</p>"
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = htmlcontent;
   </script>
```