# how to add dynamically css to head after click on a href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, head

Is it possible to import css stylesheets to `test.php` head after redirect page to test.php after click on a href link from `index` page using Javascript? If so, how can it be done?

problem is that `styles.css` not working or display in `test.php` page?

i have code like this:

**Index Page**

```
<a id="some_id" class="optional_has_click">Click Me</a>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#some_id").click(function(){

 // add dynamically css file from external link and display to head
 window.location.href = 'test.php'; 

var cssId = 'styles'; 
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.id   = cssId;
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'http://example.com/styles.css';
link.media = 'all';
head.appendChild(link);

document.write("<style>#jstree-marker-line, 
#preloader{ background:none !important}</style>");

});

});
</script>
```

**test page**

```
<div id="container">

<p>test</p>

</div>
```

Comment: See these posts for different ways of interaction between js and css http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets and http://davidwalsh.name/ways-css-javascript-interact

So I guess the options are either loading the css file with curl.js or dynamically adding the rules to your present stlyesheets (or as an inline `<style>`)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **document.write** after the page has loaded, but if you really want to add styles like this to the head of the page you could potentially try something like this:

```
$("head").append("<style>...</style>");
```

But, it's probably better to do something like this when you want to update a style on the page

```
$("#jstree-marker-line").css("background", "none");
```

Or you could have a class with the styles you need defined on the page and use jquery's [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add that class dynamically on click

Comment: problem is that `styles.css` not working or display in `test.php` page?

Comment: question is that when i click to `a href link` page redirect to `test.php`  and styles.css should be apply in test.php

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.location.href = 'test.php';` will load a different page and stop any JavaScript running after that point.

Check out this question: [How can I make JavaScript make (produce) new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004555/how-can-i-make-javascript-make-produce-new-page) as it may answer your problem, or run the rest of the script on the test page.

Also check out [@JenGettings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32022801/4143855) instead of `document.write` as it will overwrite the page.